# Convergence of reciprocal of a linear function

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

For what values of $m$ does the integral $\int_m^\infty \frac{1}{4x-16}\;dx$ converge?

I began by taking the following limit $$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{4}\int_m^k\frac{1}{x-4}\;dx=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4}\ln{|x-4|}\right)\bigg|_m^k$$

which, as far as I can tell, diverges no matter the $m$.

The next thought was that maybe the question was playing fast and loose with the term "value" and I could try letting $a\rightarrow\infty$ since the symmetry of the function suggests that the integral could be $0$.

However, splitting up the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{4x-16}\;dx=\int_{-\infty}^4\frac{1}{4x-16}\;dx+\int_4^\infty\frac{1}{4x-16}\;dx$$

just leads to divergence as well. Is there something I'm missing here? Are there truly values of $m$ for which we have convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m \ge 4$ the integral $\int_m^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-4}\;dx$ is divergent.

If $m<4$ the integral  $\int_m^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-4}\;dx =\int_m^{4}\frac{1}{x-4}\;dx+\int_4^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-4}\;dx$ is divergent.

Conclusion: there is no $m$ such that $\int_m^\infty \frac{1}{4x-16}\;dx$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

For all $m\le 4$, the integral is improper because of the singularity in the integrand. The principal value on $[m,8-m]$ is zero, but the tail still diverges.

For $m>4$, it diverges.